# Batch File Skipping If Statement

Tags: windows, batch-file

It seems that whenever I run my Batch file, everything will run, and it'll go into `checkfiles`, but it doesn't operate the if statement. Nothing is returned, it just skips right over unto the last part of the code.

```
:file_check
if exist "%psychedelia%\nhc.exe" (goto file_exists) else (timeout /t 1 /nobreak > output)
goto file_check

:file_exists
copy /Y "%~dp0version.txt" "%psychedelia%"

:checkfiles
echo in checkfiles
if exist "%psychedelia%\wa.exe" if exist "%psychedelia%\readme.txt" if exist "%psychedelia%\HD.BLB" if exist "%psychedelia%\smackw32.dll" if exist "%psychedelia%\setup95.exe" if exist "%psychedelia%\WAVistaWin7.exe" (
    echo MSGBOX "Thank you for installing the Neverhood. You may now go to your desktop and click on the Orpheus shortcut to play!" > %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs
    call %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs
    del %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs /f /q
    rename "%psychedelia%\nhc.exe" wa.exe
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > output
    taskkill.exe /F /IM setup95.exe /T
) else ( 
    echo nonexistent
    pause
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > output
    goto checkfiles
)
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your question have to do with `vbscript`? This is strictly a batch file question. Please only use tags that apply to your question. If you're not sure if it applies, read the description of the tag that shows up below it when you're selecting it. Tags are used to classify questions so that they can be located in searches, and so they get the attention of people who are interested in questions about that topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
...
echo in checkfiles
for %%f in (wa.exe 
            readme.txt 
            HD.BLB 
            smackw32.dll 
            setup95.exe 
            WAVistaWin7.exe
           ) do if not exist "%psychedelia%\%%f" (
    echo %%f nonexistent
    pause
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > output
    goto checkfiles
   )

:: all required files found

echo MSGBOX "Thank you for installing the Neverhood. You may now go to your desktop and click on the Orpheus shortcut to play!" > %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs
call %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs
del %temp%\TEMPxmessage.vbs /f /q
rename "%psychedelia%\nhc.exe" wa.exe
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > output
taskkill.exe /F /IM setup95.exe /T
```

It might be easier to maintain.

In fact, you could even write

```
set requiredfiles=wa.exe readme.txt HD.BLB smackw32.dll setup95.exe WAVistaWin7.exe
for %%f in (%requiredfiles%) do if not exist "%psychedelia%\%%f" (
...
```

which would be even easier.

Answer (score 4):

Only the last `if exist` on that line has parentheses, so the `else` only applies to that last one.  If any of the first ones evaluate to false, it will just skip the whole thing.